# Django Q AND lookup - querying for multiple entries in complex lookup

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, django-q

So I'm trying to implement an AJAX search form in my project.

My model contains a Recipe class and an Ingredient class connected by foreign key to the Recipe so that each recipe can have several ingredients.

I have a recipe entry in my db titled omelet that has 2 ingredients - egg and milk.

My query looks like so:

```
for title_ing in search_text:
    recipe_list_search = recipe_list_search & (Q(ingredients__ingredient__icontains=title_ing))
```

When searching for each ingredient separately I get the correct return, for example, my output for egg:

```
egg
(AND: ('ingredients__ingredient__icontains', 'egg'))
<QuerySet [<Recipe: Eggs>, <Recipe: omlet>, <Recipe: Pan Egg>]>
```

or milk:

```
milk
(AND: ('ingredients__ingredient__icontains', 'milk'))
<QuerySet [<Recipe: sdfsd>, <Recipe: omlet>]>
```

however, when searching for the two ingredients combined I get the following output:

```
egg milk
(AND: ('ingredients__ingredient__icontains', 'egg'))
(AND: ('ingredients__ingredient__icontains', 'egg'),('ingredients__ingredient__icontains', 'milk'))
<QuerySet []>
```

So the query won't return an entry containing both ingredients
**Any idea why that happens?**

code for my model:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
recipe = models.ForeignKey("Recipe", verbose_name=_("Recipe"), related_name="ingredients", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
quantity = models.CharField(_("Quantity"), max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
unit = models.CharField(_("Unit"), choices=fields.UNITS, blank=True, null=True, max_length=20)
ingredient = models.CharField(_("Ingredient"), max_length=100)
note = models.CharField(_("Note"), max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    _ingredient = '%s' % self.ingredient

    if self.unit:
        _ingredient = '%s %s' % (self.get_unit_display(), _ingredient)

    if self.quantity:
        _ingredient = '%s %s' % (self.quantity, _ingredient)
    #python anywhere doesnt register len for somereason so should be changed
    if len(self.note):
       _ingredient = '%s - %s' % (_ingredient, self.note)

    return _ingredient

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _("Ingredient")
    verbose_name_plural = _("Ingredients")
```

and the view:

```
def search(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    search_text = request.POST['search_text']
else:
    search_text = ''

recipe_list_search = ''
print(search_text)
search_text = search_text.split()

recipe_list_search = Q()
for title_ing in search_text:
    recipe_list_search = recipe_list_search & (Q(ingredients__ingredient__icontains=title_ing))
    print(recipe_list_search)
f_search=Recipe.objects.filter(recipe_list_search).distinct()
print(f_search)
context = {'recipe_list_search': f_search}
return render(request, 'stage9/ajax_search.html', context)
```

Might be a noob question but I would highly appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: i did not delete just edited the title

Comment: What would be the output? Untill you say what you need its hard to rectify the code

Comment: sorry my bad but your edit hasn't improved this question one bit.

Comment: I'm looking for the omelet entry so the output would be egg milk
(AND: ('ingredients__ingredient__icontains', 'egg'))
(AND: ('ingredients__ingredient__icontains', 'egg'),('ingredients__ingredient__icontains', 'milk'))
<QuerySet [<Recipe: omlet>]>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Maybe you should try to add .distinct() ?

Comment: Thanks but iv solved it by manually constructing the queries, I just thought there might a django method for handling complex lookups for multiple entries. I guess it's also me not being clear enough with my question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using AND operator on querysets, try to use itertools for chaining.

```
from itertools import chain


your_queryset = #("whatever_you_queryset_is") ie, Q(ingredients__ingredient__icontains=title_ing) 

for title_ing in search_text:
    recipe_list_search = list(chain(recipe_list_search, your_queryset))
```

May be this could make your code some sense.

Comment: Ok so chain will give the same effect as using the or operator '|' , meaning the input "egg milk" will return all recipes having either "milk" or "egg" as their ingredient. I want AND, so it will return only those recipes having both.